# Streaming video with socket io

Tags: node.js, video, socket.io, streaming

I am having some difficulty streaming a video file with socket.io and node. My video file is on my server, and I am using the fs module to read it into a readStream. I am them passing chunks of data to a mediasource on the client side, which feeds into an html 5 video tag.

Although the client is receiving the chunks (I'm logging them), and I am appending the chunks to the buffer of the media source, nothing shows up in the video tag.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my code:

Client side:

```
  var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
  var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
    document.getElementById('video').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(event) {
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        console.log(sourceBuffer);
        socket.on('chunk', function (data) {
            if(!sourceBuffer.updating){
                sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data);
                console.log(data);
            }

        });
        socket.emit('go',{})
    });
```

Server side:
var stream = fs.createReadStream(window.currentvidpath);

```
socket.on('go', function(){ 
  console.log('WENT');
    stream.addListener('data',function(data){
      console.log('VIDDATA',data);
      socket.emit('chunk',data);
    })
  })
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the chunks don't arrive as Base64? I would assume, since socket.io uses JSON, that any binary data would be encoded before being sent... but I might be mixing things up. You should check.

Comment: @Myst - webSocket and socket.io have binary modes if set that way.

Comment: @jfriend00, Good to know. However, I didn't see that in the server code the OP posted... If the server is set that way, that's probably better, since Base64 increases the overhead (encoding, decoding and bandwidth).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fact that you only append the source buffer if there it is not updating
`if(!sourceBuffer.updating){
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data);
        console.log(data);
 }`

Heres my console after I added a else and log the times it don't append

```
SourceBuffer {mode: "segments", updating: false, buffered: TimeRanges, timestampOffset: 0, appendWindowStart: 0…}
site.html:24 connect
site.html:17 ArrayBuffer {}
30 site.html:20 not appending
```

So it appended the one chunk of the video and ignored 30

You should store the ones that aren't appended in a array. Then just make a loop with set Interval